# Powershell: A parameter with the name was defined multiple times for the command

Tags: powershell

Any idea, how to get a Switch running with Powershell?

```
myscript.ps1 -Debug
```

**A parameter with the name 'Debug' was defined multiple times for the command.**

**My Script**

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [switch]$Debug
    )
    
    if ($Debug) {
     Start-Transcript -Path "Debug.log" -Append -Force
}
```

Comment: `-Debug` is already a standard parameter inherited for each function. Choose a different name.

Comment: Or, alternatively, just roll with it and use the `$DebugPreference` the built-in switch sets without using your own.

Answer (score 5):

When you create an advanced function or script that uses the `CmdletBinding` attribute or the `Parameter` attribute, PowerShell adds [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1#long-description), including `-Debug` to your function. So you should not add these on your own.

To test for the `-Debug` common parameter, it is more flexible to check the value of the related [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.1) `$DebugPreference`. This works because `-Debug` overrides `$DebugPreference` within the scope of the script.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param ()
    
if( $DebugPreference -eq 'Continue' ) {
    Start-Transcript -Path "Debug.log" -Append -Force
}
```

Now you can enable debug logging for your script either using the parameter...

```
.\myscript.ps1 -Debug
```

... or the preference variable:

```
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
.\myscript.ps1
```